# How to set "mappedBy" in a subclass of an entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to split an existing JPA-Entity into a POJO superclass and an Entity subclass. I want to put the POJO superclass into a library project, that can be referenced by other projects, that do not use JPA.

My old/existing code successfully declared a OneToMany-relationship like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="petOwner")
    public List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I want to split it into this superclass:

```
public class CommonPerson {
    public List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**The question:** How could a appropriate jpa subclass look like? Can I set `mappedBy` in a subclass?

What I tried:

```
@Entity
// not possible: @AttributeOverride (has no "mappedBy" or "OneToMany")
// not possible: @AssociationOverride (has no "mappedBy" or "OneToMany")
public class JpaPerson extends CommonPerson {
}
```

I'm using Hibernate JPA api 2.1.

Comment: Never actually tried that but it should work if you override the getter and annotate that.

Comment: Just bear in mind that if you are planning on mixing field and property access type, you will need to specify that using @Access annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @petros-splinakis !

I'm now using something like this:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class JpaPerson extends CommonPerson {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="petOwner")
    public List<Pet> getPets() {
        return pets;
    }

    public void setPets(List<Pet> pets) {
        this.pets = pets;
    }

}
```

And it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the **@Transient annotation in the MappedSuperclass method**, you can use any other JPA annotation in the same method's subclass. So you can 'extend' the JPA annotations in the subclass.